# Best practices for making HTTP Requests from a stateless bean

Tags: http, ejb, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-tomee

I am planning to use Apache HttpClient with BasicHttpClientConnectionManager on a TOMEE stateless bean to perform HTTP GET/POST/DELETE requests to a remote server. Are there any gotchas with this approach ? Does HttpClient spawn new threads that negatively impact EJB container?

Are there any other alternatives? How do you usually perform http request from your webserver to other servers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Tomee you can use the JAX-RS client builtin to Tomee. You can find more information on it in the Java EE tutorial (chapter 30) [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-client001.htm#BABBIHEJ).

e.g.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String name = client.target("http://example.com/webapi/hello")
        .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        .get(String.class);
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately we are still on javaee6